# Either remove this useless object instantiation of class "EligibilityImport" or use it

Tags: laravel, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I'm using SonarQube to scan my Laravel application and it doesn't like the following code:

```
class EligibilityImportJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable,
        InteractsWithQueue,
        Queueable,
        SerializesModels;

    /** @var string */
    protected $file;

    /** @var int */
    protected $mode;

    public function __construct(string $file, $mode)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $file = $this->file;
        $mode = $this->mode;

        new EligibilityImport($file, $mode); // Doesn't like this line
    }
}
```

It's giving me following error: `Either remove this useless object instantiation of class "EligibilityImport" or use it`. How can I fix this? Below is the `EligibilityImport` class which imports or removes data from the database and comes from CSV file:

```
final class EligibilityImport
{
    const MODE_APPEND = 1;
    const MODE_PURGE = 2;

    const MODES = [
        self::MODE_APPEND => 'append',
        self::MODE_PURGE => 'purge'
    ];

    /** @var string */
    protected $file;

    /** @var int */
    protected $mode;

    /** @var array */
    protected $cache = [];

    public function __construct($file, $mode = self::MODE_APPEND)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->mode = $mode;

        $this->process();
    }

    protected function process()
    {
        $file = $this->file;
        $mode = $this->mode;
        $path = storage_path('app/imports/' . $file);

        if (is_file($path)) {
            $csv = Reader::createFromPath($path, 'r');
            $csv->setHeaderOffset(0);

            $records = $csv->getRecords();

            foreach ($records as $record) {
                $companyName = $record['company'] ?? null;

                if ( ! empty($companyName)) {
                    $company = $this->cache['companies'][$companyName] ?? null;

                    if (empty($company)) {
                        $company = Company::where('name', $companyName)->first();

                        if ($company !== null) {
                            $this->cache['companies'][$companyName] = $company;
                        }
                    }

                    if ($company !== null) {
                        $eligibility = null;
                        $skip = false;

                        $firstName = $record['first_name'] ?? null;
                        $lastName = $record['last_name'] ?? null;
                        $email = $record['email'] ?? null;
                        $ein = $record['ein'] ?? null;

                        if ( ! empty($email)) {
                            $eligibility = $company
                                ->eligibilities()
                                ->where('email_hash', sha1($email))
                                ->first();

                            if ($eligibility !== null) {
                                $skip = true;

                                if ($mode == self::MODE_PURGE) {
                                    $eligibility->delete();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if ( ! empty($ein)) {
                            $eligibility = $company
                                ->eligibilities()
                                ->where('ein_hash', sha1($ein))
                                ->first();

                            if ($eligibility !== null) {
                                $skip = true;

                                if ($mode == self::MODE_PURGE) {
                                    $eligibility->delete();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if ($mode == self::MODE_APPEND && ! $skip) {

                            if ( ! empty($firstName) && ! empty($lastName) && ( ! empty($email) || ! empty($ein))) {
                                $eligibility = new Eligibility();
                                $eligibility->fill($record);

                                $company->eligibilities()->save($eligibility);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @unlink($path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're correct. I've initially entered a code from another error. I've updated the original question and provided more code for you to see.

Comment: Thanks. You have in fact posted the correct code now. See my answer below. :-) See why posting the correct code in the form of that MRE makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Laravel or Sonar at all, but I can see that the compiler is correctly complaining about the line you've indicated.

```
public function handle(): void
{
    $file = $this->file;
    $mode = $this->mode;

    new EligibilityImport($file, $mode); // Doesn't like this line
}
```

It's complaining because you're creating a new instance of `EligibilityImport` and then immediately discarding it, which means that there's no reason at all to be creating it in the first place (just as the compilier message says). If you read the words in

> Either remove this useless object instantiation of class "EligibilityImport" or use it.

the compiler is telling you exactly what I've written - either remove that line of code entirely, or do something with the object instance you're creating like saving a reference to it.

The proper way to create an object instance is the form

```
someVar = new SombObject()
```

which creates the new instance and stores a reference to it to use in subsequent code. If you need to use that instance, you need to save that reference, or you have no way to do anything with it. If you don't need to use it, then delete the line of code entirely, as it's meaningless (and in some languages can be a memory leak).